# Шаблон пагинации cakephp 3.0

Tags: cakephp

Нужно сделать пагинацию на странице, не такую как на остальных страницах.

Основная пагинация имеет вот такой шаблон

```html
$this->Paginator->templates([
            'nextActive'   => '<li class="pag-next"><a rel="next" href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a></li>',
            'nextDisabled' => '<li class="pag-next disabled"><a href="" onclick="return false;">{{text}}</a></li>',
            'prevActive'   => '<li class="pag-prev"><a rel="prev" href="{{url}}">{{text}}</a></li>',
            'prevDisabled' => '<li class="pag-prev disabled"><a href="" onclick="return false;">{{text}}</a></li>',
            'number'       => '<option value="{{url}}">{{text}}</option>',
            'current'      => '<option selected="selected" value="{{url}}">{{text}}</option>'
        ]);
```

Нужно создать новый шаблон, и чтобы он применялся только на страницах где он нужен.

И еще одна проблемка, что в проекте изпользуется шаблонизатор smarty.

Comment: `smarty` эт проблема? оО В чем сложность то возникает? шаблоны вы параметром передаете, передайте другие где надо. вообще, мне кажется, что перемудрено у вас все. Мне дак как то не приходилось еще переписывать стандартные шаблоны пагинатора.

Comment: @teran эти параметры я передаю с src/view/SamrtyView.php. как мне их передать с другого места?

Answer (score 0):

Может немного не в тему ответ, но в моей, может и не большой, практике использования `CakePHP` переписывать в явном виде шаблоны пагинатора мне не приходилось. Для вывода пагинации я использую отедльный smarty-шаблон.
Вот допустим мы выбрали данные:

```
 $st = TableRegistry::get('SomeTable');
 $query = $st->find()->where([ ... ])->orderDesc('id');  
 $items = $this->paginate($query);
 $this->set('items', $items);
```

в шаблоне вывода `src\templates\MyController\index.tpl` вывели список элементов и добавляем smarty-шаблон пагинации:

```
{foreach $items as $i}
<li>{$i.title|escape}</li>
{/foreach}
{include "../Common/_paginate.tpl"}
```

надо по-разному оформить вывод пагинации - рисуйте несколько разных  шаблонов `_paginateX.tpl` или передавайте туда разные опции.

У меня шаблон пагинации выглядит следующим образом:

```
{if $paginate_options|default:null}
    {$this->Paginator->options($paginate_options)}
{/if}

<div class="paginator text-right">
    <ul class="list-unstyled list-inline">
        {if $this->Paginator->hasPrev()}
            {$this->Paginator->prev("«")}
        {/if}

        {$this->Paginator->numbers()}

        {if $this->Paginator->hasNext()}
            {$this->Paginator->next("»")}
        {/if}
    </ul>
</div>
```

может это, конечно, несколько нарушает концепцию самого хэлпера, но дает полную свободу при генерации пагнинации. Но если требуется как то кардинально изменить пагинацию, то проще сделать так, чем  настраивать шаблоны. Такая техника шаблонов для состояний пагинатора (используемая в cakephp и приведенная в вопросе), к сожалению, несколько противоречит MVC модели, и выносит представление куда то на уровень контроллера, или где еще оно настраивается.

Comment: спасибо за ответ. Но это действительно не совсем то. Фрагмент моего кода с src/view/SamrtyView.php. это врятли нарушает соглашения. И вся проблема в том что `$this->Paginator->numbers()` генерит `<option value="{{url}}">{{text}}</option>`. Если я поменяю в SamrtyView.php то изменится на всем сайте, а мне нужно только на некоторых разделах

Comment: @SanyaLavrechko ну вот как по мне, то задача вьюхи в данном случае - обработать нужный формат шаблона, в данном случае tpl. Хз стоит ли грузить вьюшку другим функционалом. в целом то же самое вы можете устанавливать и в контроллере. Либо передавать во вьюшку какой либо параметр, и на основании его уже либо заменить шаблоны во вью-классе либо нет.

Comment: я вообще к тому, что jnyjcbntkmyj mvc, `v` будет скорее tpl-шаблоном, а не `SmartyView` классом. Поэтому мешанина html и пхп-код это плохо, как и всегда, и тут не исключение. Так что и в части пагинатора. и в части шаблонов form-хэлпера, применяемое в cakephp решение мне не очень нравится, несколько костыльно, на мой взгляд.

Comment: как еще одна вариация,  настройки эти вы можете применить и непосредственно в tpl-шаблоне, то есть прямо перед вызовом пагинатора в шаблоне добавить вызов `{$this->Paginator->templates(...)}`, и эту часть можно так же вынести в отдельный tpl и инклудить там где требуется.